# MUI Datagrid rendercell getValue return undefined

Tags: material-ui, getvalue

Since I pushed my code on production, I cant call anymore getValue inside renderCell

Environnement is the same as dev by the way

Here is the columns def:

```
const columns = [
        {
            field: 'edit',
            headerName: 'Edit',
            sortable: false,
            width: 78,
            renderCell: (params) => (
                <div>
                 <EditProduct defaultCats={props.defaultCats} prodId={params.getValue('id')} productIdGL={params.getValue('productId')} />
                </div>  
              ),
            align: "left",
        },
        {
            field: 'active',
            headerName: 'Off / On',
            width: 104,
            renderCell: (params) => (
                <div><CustomSwitch
                    checked={Boolean(params.value)}
                    onChange={() => myswitch(params.getValue('id'), Boolean(params.value))}
                    name="switch-"
                    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'primary checkbox' }}
                ></CustomSwitch>
                </div>  
              ),
              align: "left",
        },
        { field: 'category_name', headerName: 'Catégorie', width: 120 },
        { field: 'item_name', headerName: 'Nom du produit', width: 220 },
        {
          field: 'price',
          headerName: 'Prix de vente',
          type: 'number',
          width: 140,

        },
        {
          field: 'profit',
          headerName: 'Profit par vente',
          type: 'number',
          width: 160,
          alt: 'Test'
        },
        { field: 'type', headerName: 'Type', width: 90 },
        { field: 'id', headerName: '#', width: 80 },
      ];
```

Error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
```

Any help appreciate since this bug occur only on production

mui-core: 4.11.4
mui-datagrid: 4.0.0-alpha.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params.getValue(params.id, 'id') || ''
```

Instead of

```
params.getValue('id')
```